# Retrofit @Body POST

Tags: android, retrofit

I have problem with retrofit POST request. I try to send Object with few fields, and array inside. I read that the best solution is to do it with @Body. However server returns error  - null project is being sent. This is my post method :

```
  @POST("/api/mobile/{language}/{apiVersion}/beacons/try-save-settings")
    void trySaveBeaconParams(
            @Body EonBeaconModel model,

            Callback<BasicResponse<Object>> callback);
```

This is my EonBeaconModel.class :

```
@Table(name = "eonBeacon")
public class EonBeaconModel extends Model {
    @Column(unique = true, onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE, index = true)
    public long beacon_id;
    @Column
    public long bridge_id;
    @Column
    public long mesh_id;
    @Column
    public String name;
    @Column
    public String location;
    @Column
    public String mac_address;
    @Column
    public String firmware;
    @Column
    public String pcb_revision;
    @Column
    public int battery_level;
    @Column
    public String password;
    @Column
    public String assigned_bridge_id;

    @Column(name="Eeid")
    public Eeid eeid;
    @Column(name="Etlm")
    public Etlm etlm;
    @Column
    public Euid euid;
    @Column(name="Eurl")
    public Eurl eurl;
    @Column(name="Ib")
    public IbModel ibBeaconModel;
    @Column
    public String jsonIB;
    @Column
    public String jsonEeid;
    @Column
    public String jsonEtlm;
    @Column
    public String jsonEuid;
    @Column
    public String jsonEurl;
    @Column
    public boolean isBeacon;
    @Column(name="sleep_modes")
    public List<SleepMode> sleep_modes;
    @Column
    public String jsonSleep;
```

this is how I create Callback:

```
@Subscribe
    public void validateNewBeaconData(ValidateNewBeaconDataCommand command) {
        Callback<BasicResponse<Object>> callback = new Callback<BasicResponse<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(BasicResponse<Object> basicResponse, Response response) {
                if (ResponseStatus.SUCCESS.statusCode == basicResponse.status) {
                    EventBus.post(new BeaconsSettingsValidatedEvent());
                    Log.e(TAG, "success: ");
                }
                else {
                    EventBus.post(new NetworkFailureEvent(ResponseStatus.getByStatus(basicResponse.status), basicResponse.status_msg));
                    Log.e(TAG, "failure validate: " );

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                EventBus.post(new NetworkFailureEvent(ResponseStatus.NETWORK_ERROR, messageString));
                Log.e(TAG, "failure: " + error.getCause() );

            }
        };
        Log.e(TAG, "validateNewBeaconData: " + command.model.eurl.interval );
        service.trySaveBeaconParams(command.model
                ,
             callback);


    }
```

And this is my Command class :

```
public class ValidateNewBeaconDataCommand extends ApiCommand {
   public EonBeaconModel model;


    public ValidateNewBeaconDataCommand(EonBeaconModel model) {

       this.model=model;
    }
}
```

I've checked it on debug and when Callback is being called command isn't null - it has all fields from EonBeaconModel object. The only problem is with sending it to server. Any help please ?

POST should look like this :

[image]

Comment: check your URL `{language}/{apiVersion}` use @path to fill these 2 values

Comment: URL is correct.

Comment: have you checked URL using `POSTMAN` ??

Comment: Yes I have, URL is correct cause without array sleep_modes everything works fine with "@Field" annotations. Unfortunatelly I can't post an array with "@Field"

Comment: Refer to this link here: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body

Comment: plse  add ur json

Comment: @RissmonSuresh I added to the post.

Comment: @TodorKostov I did exactly as suggests in that link :/

Comment: where u are passing your EonBeaconModel  object in retrofit call

Comment: public void validateNewBeaconData -> method is added to the post :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to append a slash at the end of the POST Url, like:

```
@POST("/api/mobile/{language}/{apiVersion}/beacons/try-save-settings/")
```

Comment: No , that's not the thing :/